# Delete Date using backspace or delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have created multiple dates selection for multiple input fields using jQuery [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Now Problem is i want to delete any date form cursor position[image: datepicker example]

External Link to Jquery ui

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Multile Date selection input fields

```
<input type="text" class="dates_opted dates_opted_1">
<br><br>
<input type="text" class="dates_opted dates_opted_2">
```

jQuery and jQuery ui Js file cdn link

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Js code

```
    <script>
    function cleanArray(actual) {
      var newArray = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
        if (actual[i]) {
          newArray.push(actual[i]);
        }
      }
      return newArray;
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.dates_opted').each(function(index){
          var dates=[];
       $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(){
       dates=cleanArray(dates);
        dates.push($(this).val());
        //console.log(dates);
        $(this).val(dates);


      },showAnim :'slide',
    minDate: 0

    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
          var datesString=$(this).val().split(",");
           dates=[];
          for(var i=0 ; i<datesString.length-1;i++){

            dates.push(datesString[i]);
          }
          $(this).focus();
          $(this).blur();
          $(this).val(dates);


        }
    });
         });
    });
</script>
```

`Here is` **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Daulat/9sdamnnb/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function(e)
{
   if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46)
      {
         var datesString=$(this).val().split(",");
         dates=[];
```

Get the cursors position and found the index of date you need to remove

```
      cix=$(this).selectionStart;
      ix=Math.floor(cix/9);
```

Run trough all array and skip that value in new array

```
      for(var i=0 ; i<datesString.length;i++)
         {
             if(i!=ix)
               {
                  dates.push(datesString[i]);
               }
         }
      $(this).focus();
      $(this).blur();
      $(this).val(dates);
}
```